# Let $A$ be an $1$-dimensional Noether integral domain. Let $I$ be an nonzero ideal of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension

Let $A$ be an $1$-dimensional Noether integral domain.
Let $I$ be an nonzero ideal of $A$.
Then, I want to prove the number of prime ideals of $A$ containing $I$ is finite.

I tried to prove with contradiction.
Let $p_1, p_2, \dots$ be infinitely many prime ideals containing $I$. I couldn't proceed. I may use Krull dimension $1$, but in vain.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What we want to show is equivalent to showing that $A/I$ only has finitely many prime ideals. Because $(0) \subsetneq I$ and $(0)$ is a prime ideal (as $A$ is an integral domain), we have that $\mathrm{dim}(A/I) \leq 0$. Also, being a quotient of a Noetherian ring, $A/I$ is Noetherian. Thus $A/I$ is (at most) zero-dimensional and Noetherian, thus $A/I$ is Artinian and has only finitely many prime ideals.

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get $dim(A/I)≦0$ ?

Comment: Suppose you have a chain of prime ideals $\overline{P_1} \subsetneq \overline{P_2} \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq \overline{P_n}$ in $A/I$, then we can lift those prime ideals to prime ideals in $A$ by using the projection $\pi:A \to A/I$ and setting $P_i:=\pi^{-1}(\overline{P_i})$, then we get a chain of prime ideals $0 \subsetneq P_1 \subsetneq P_2 \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq P_n$, so using $\mathrm{dim}(A)=1$, we get $n=1$